# How to get Android storage locations

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm struggling with something that should be dead simple which is the dreaded problem of getting the storage directory paths, be it internal or exteral -- SD cards or OTG devices -- .

​

I was expecting a simple call such as getExternalStorageDirectory() or something of the like , but to my surprise I found I had to do a lot of hacks and workarounds to guarantee that my function works with all OEMs and different versions of Android.

​

I found a solution here which uses the following three Environment Variables

val rawExternalStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")

val rawSecondaryStoragesStr = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")

val rawEmulatedStorageTarget = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET")

I kinda get what the first and second variables are -- but with Android, never be sure of anything! :D --

But I've absolutely no idea what the third variable is or what it does ,, could someone please explain to me what it is and how I should use it?

Comment: getFilesDIr(), getExternalFilesDIr() and getExternalFilesDirs(). Forget the ones you tried. getExternalStorageDirectory() works until Android.Q.

Comment: `a simple call such as getExternalStorageDirectory() ` Well that works. Did you try?

Comment: It works but only for the internal storage of the device i.e. no sd cards or such.

Comment: What I need is something which allows me to get to any storage space regardless of the OEM , I know many devs have a hard time with Samsung for example

Comment: `i.e. no sd cards or such` Try getExternalFilesDirs(). The second item.

Comment: Since you have limited access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+, and almost no access to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or removable storage on Android 10+, I recommend that you reconsider your entire approach to whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CommonsWare first of all, I'm an old  fan and a close follower of yours .. and I've been keeping a close eye to your blog posts about the scoped storage but never really thought that google would go on with a move like that ,so I didn't really consider it a "thing".

Comment: so you think I should go for the SAF framework and all that document tree stuff instead?

Comment: @gemy845: Well, I don't know what you are trying to build. If it is tied closely to media, perhaps querying the `MediaStore` will be a better choice. If it is something that absolutely needs the filesystem, use the plural storage methods on `Context` (`getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, `getExternalMediaDirs()`), recognizing that you don't necessarily have access outside of those and that the user might have difficulty finding those paths. For many conventional scenarios, though, SAF is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on **OnCreate** of class where you required.

```
private String DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

to obtain absolute path